# how to remove a bitmap from an imageview?

Tags: android

i am decoding an image from a url and i have an array of different urls,i want to show the bitmap images decoded from the url in the imageview but only the image from last url is showing.I am not able to understand the problem.

```
String  [] imageLocation={"http://wallbase1.org/thumbs/rozne/thumb-499842.jpg","http:   //ns3002439.ovh.net/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2493796.jpg","http://ns3002439.ovh.net/thumbs/rozne/thumb-2486664.jpg"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       image_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

   while(i<2)
    {
  bitmap=loadImage(imageLocation[i]);
    image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   Animation rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoadImageActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
     findViewById(R.id.imageview).startAnimation(rotate);
     i++;
        }

 }

 public  Bitmap loadImage(String image_location){

      URL imageURL = null;

      try {
          imageURL = new URL(image_location);
        } 

      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      try {
          HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.connect();
          InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();


          bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//Convert to bitmap

      }
      catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();
      }
    return bitmap;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to continuously change the bitmap being shown in the ImageView? Your question isn't exactly clear....

Comment: Well, you are in a loop setting images into the same imageview.  Each subsequent images overwrites the previous one in the imageview and hence the last one stays.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: yes i want to change the bitmap shown in imageview ,let's say in every 2-3 seconds